# PayPalの定期決済の明細取得について

Tags: paypal

Merchant API等で、プロファイルの決済情報のような情報って取得できるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

プロファイルIDで取得可能です。TransactionSearch APIで、定期支払プロファイルID(PROFILEID)をキーに取引情報を取得してみてください。

TransactionSearch API
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/TransactionSearch_API_Operation_NVP/

Comment: 無事取引情報を取得できました。ありがとうございます！